# Doesnt work update query in queue Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In controller i need to update user's balance after 24hours,i send price of product and seller id to queue, then i'm trying to update user balance by queue, but the queue fires without error's, and the balance in the database does not change. How can i solve this?

wd

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\User;

class CreditMoney implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;


    protected $price;

    protected $seller_id;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($price, $seller_id)
    {
        $this->$price = $price;
        $this->$seller_id = $seller_id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $manySellery = $this->price - ($this->price * (5 / 100));
        $balance = User::where('id', $this->seller_id)->value('balance');
        $money = $balance + $manySellery;
        return User::where(['id' => $this->seller_id])->update(array('balance' => $money));
    }
}
```

```
public function confirm($id)
    {
        $data = Product::where('id', $id)->select(array('price', 'dispute', 'seller_id', 'is_confirmed'))->first();
        if ($data->is_confirmed && !is_null($data->dispute)) return redirect()->to(route('index'));

        Product::where('id', $id)->update(array('is_confirmed' => 1));
        
        dispatch(new CreditMoney($data->price,$data->seller_id));
        
        return redirect()->to(route('order', $id))->with('confirm', 'Confirmed.');
    }
```

Comment: If you call the update method from controller. Does it work fine?

Comment: Yes, it's work's fine

Comment: As per the comment, _The error was pretty stupid, I wrote "$this->$price" instead of "$this->price". Sorry_, by the OP, this was caused by a typo. I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1):

use this code snippet

```
return User::where('id', $this->seller_id)->update(['balance' => $money]);
```

Comment: Didn't worked too

Comment: try to print seller_id value in handle and check if it is containing the correct value

Comment: Thanks, now I see that for some reason the parameters are not sent to the job

Comment: Change this:

    `protected $price;`

    `protected $seller_id;`

to:

   `public $price;`

     `public $seller_id;`

Answer (score 1):

The error was pretty stupid, I wrote "$this->$price" instead of "$this->price".
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
return User::where('id', $this->seller_id)->update(array('balance' => $money));
```

Comment: Didn't worked :(

Comment: @Hotring try to debug and see where it get's stuck. You can try to dd the User instance for example to see if it finds one

Comment: Thanks, now I see that for some reason the parameters are not sent to the job

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `User` Model, check the fillable array. and see if you have added the `balance` in that array.

Update method only updates the values in DB if the column is added to `fillable` attributes.

Comment: that should have thrown an error tho

Comment: Already added to fillable